# angular-formly and jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, angular-formly

I'm trying to add a jquery-ui datepicker in a angular-formly template.

I have a simple directive to make the jquery-ui datepicker working in angular.

```html
app.directive("myDatePicker", function() {

    var datePickerDateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
    var momentDateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        startDate: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


        element.datepicker({
          dateFormat: datePickerDateFormat
        });

        element.datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);      

        
      }
    };
  })
```

This directive is well working in a classic input.

When I'm trying to use it in a angular formly template, the date picker is well displayed but when I click to select a date, I have this message :

> Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker

you can find an exemple [here](http://jsbin.com/mixozid/edit?html,js,output)

Does anybody figure out with that kind of error ?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why are you trying to use your own directive instead of formly UI Datepicker ?

Comment: Yes, we are using Jquery UI datepicker in my entreprise. I try to use this datepicker before swith to the UI Datepicker. It's less impacting fir us.

Comment: Is this example worth http://embed.plnkr.co/RwePfw/